I got the warning log LambdaLoggingAspect has not been applied
I added the powertools-logging dependency on our project.
And I build our project, and success. but I got the warning message as follow.
[INFO] --- aspectj:1.13.1:compile (default) @ our_project_name ---
[INFO] Showing AJC message detail for messages of types: [error, warning, fail]
[WARNING] advice defined in software.amazon.lambda.powertools.logging.internal.LambdaLoggingAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
    /my_home_directory/.m2/repository/software/amazon/lambda/powertools-logging/1.18.0/powertools-logging-1.18.0.jar!software/amazon/lambda/powertools/logging/internal/LambdaLoggingAspect.class:0

I add the dependency in the pom.xml as follow.
            <dependency>
                <groupId>software.amazon.lambda</groupId>
                <artifactId>powertools-logging</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.20.1</version>
            </dependency>
・
・
・
            <plugin>
                <groupId>dev.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.13.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>1.9.20.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <forceAjcCompile>true</forceAjcCompile>
                    <sources/>
                    <weaveDirectories>
                        <weaveDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</weaveDirectory>
                    </weaveDirectories>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <complianceLevel>11</complianceLevel>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>software.amazon.lambda</groupId>
                            <artifactId>powertools-logging</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

I build by jdk 11.
Why is this happen?
If you have any idea, let me know how to fix it.
Or if I can ignore it, let me know too.
I investigated the github repository.

whether you can or cannot ignore it, is up to you. Are there error messages later on in your running? Does your code do as you want it to do?

I see. I do not still run our code on the environment. I am going to check how our code do as I want it to do on our environment.
